# Scala cannot access getter methods when using implicit type-class (variance + polymorphism)

Tags: scala, polymorphism, covariance, typeclass, implicit

In the following example I don't understand why I cannot access the getter methods on the `M1`, `M2`, `M3` classes.

I need the trait `S` to be covariant with `T` in order to implement the `runSeq` method. Because of that the `toto` method needs to take `U` as superclass of `T`. When I do that, I can no longer access the constructor fields of the argument `t`.

If I remove the covariance requirement (`+T`) everything works but then I dont know how to implement the `runSeq` method (in particular it needs to receive an implicit type-class object).

```
abstract class M
case class M1(s: String) extends M
case class M2(i: Int) extends M
case class M3(b: Boolean) extends M
trait S[+T] {
  def follow(s: String): String
  def toto[U >: T](t: U): String
}
implicit object S1 extends S[M1] {
  val m1 = M1("1") // this is for testing only
  def follow(s: String): String = s + ".M1." + toto(m1)
  def toto[M1](t: M1): String = "toto" + t.s // ERROR: cannot resolve "s"
}
implicit object S2 extends S[M2] {
  val m2 = M2(2) // for testing purposes only
  def follow(s: String): String = s + ".M2." + toto(m2)
  def toto[M2](t: M2): String = "toto" + t.i.toString // ERROR: cannot resolve "i"
}
implicit object S3 extends S[M3] {
  val m3 = M3(true) // for testing purposes
  def follow(s: String): String = s + ".M3." + toto(m3)
  def toto[M3](t: M3): String = "toto" + t.b.toString // ERROR: cannot resolve "b"
}
def run[T: S](s: String): String = implicitly[S[T]].follow(s)

run[M1]("run")

def runSeq(seq: S[M]*)(s: String) =
  seq.foldLeft(s)((st, tg) => run(st)(tg))

runSeq(S3,S2,S1)("runSeq")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that `def toto[U >: T](t: U): String` is basically the same as `def toto(t: Any): String`, since `Any` satisfies the bound for any possible `T`. This also explains why you can't access `T`'s members in `t`. Note that variance is irrelevant for this.

> T is only covariant because runSeq needs to take a sequence of S[T] with various types of T derived from M. Is there a better way of doing that?

`def runSeq(seq: S[_ <: M]*)` corresponds directly to this. However, you are likely to run into type erasure problems: given an `S[_ <: M]`, you can't know its actual type parameter or check if an `M` is of a suitable type. Look up `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` for solutions. Again, this is a problem independent of variance.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. I also reached the conclusion that variance was not appropriate. I have to fix `runSeq` as you suggest. My initial goal was avoiding type matching.

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing with the type parameters (e.g. `M1` with `def toto[M1](t: M1): String = "toto" + t.s`).

Considering `trait S[+T] { ... def toto[U >: T](t: U): String }` for `object S1 extends S[M1]`, a compliant `toto` should be implemented as bellow.

```
def toto[U >: M1](t: U): String = "toto" + t.s
```

In such case, with `U >: M1`, the type system cannot prove that `t` is defined `s: String`.

> The type constraints and variance seems wrong there.

Comment: Thanks. I see what's the problem now. The reason I got this wrong is U should really only be allowed to equal T but since T is covariant that doesnt work. T is only covariant because runSeq needs to take a sequence of S[T] with various types of T derived from M. Is there a better way of doing that? Note that M represent messages and S the processing step of those messages.

Comment: Start with a simpler design (using contravariance on a typeparam for which a `>:` is then used seems overcomplicated)